# Spark: Create nested dataframe from a flat one

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, schema

From the following dataframe:

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq(
  (1, "value11", "value12"),
  (2, "value21", "value22"),
  (3, "value31", "value32")
)
val df = data.toDF("id", "v1", "v2")
```

Is it possible to turn df to a nested dataframe, whose schema is:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType),
  StructField("nested", StructType(Array(
    StructField("value1", StringType),
    StructField("value2", StringType)
    )))
  ))
```

I know there is a RDD solution:

```
spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd.map(row => Row(row.get(0), Row(row.get(1), row.get(2))), schema)
```

But I want to apply it dynamically to many columns, this will lead to a lot of boilerplate code.

is there an easier way?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do is using `struct`

You can also rename the columns if you want as

```
val newColumns = List("value1", "value2")
columns.zip(newColumns).foldLeft(df){(acc, name) =>
  acc.withColumnRenamed(name._1, name._2)
}

//list the columns names you want to nested 
val columns = df.columns.tail

//use struct to create new fields and drop all columns 
val finalDF = df.withColumn("nested", struct(columns.map(col(_)):_*))..drop(columns:_*)
```

Final Schema:

```
finalDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- nested: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- v1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- v2: string (nullable = true)
```